# How to deploy laravel to server using ftp

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm newbie on Laravel. I have to upload laravel project to Linux server(CentOS).  Customer provide me ftp path. For example 10.222.20.10/srp. So I put all files into that path and after edited database inside .env file. I run 10.222.20.10/srp on webbrowser but I getting error 'This page is not working, error 500'. I attached picture as below. Appreciated for advise and thank you very much.

[image: ftp]

[image: error 500]

Comment: you can look into the log file for more details about the issue

Comment: Hi, I didn't see helpful info from log file. It's 97MB file size but records look messy.

Comment: May be keep some link of tutorial for deploy laravel. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please Follow this Steps:

1.
 Copy all contents inside the **/project/public** directory to **project/**
Remember to copy the **public/.htaccess** to the **project/** also
Now let’s modify the **www/index.php** to reflect the new structure. Don’t modify the **project/public/index.php**, okay? Only modify **www/index.php**, remember this!!!

Find the following line

```
require __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/autoload.php’;
$app = require_once __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/app.php’;
```

And update them to the correct paths as following

```
require __DIR__.’/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php’;
$app = require_once __DIR__.’/../project/bootstrap/app.php’;
```

2. Set permision 777 project/storage and project/bootstrap/cache

Comment: Hi, my project doesn't have 'public' folder as pic https://ibb.co/9TXcctC.

Comment: Oh. You have configured local to run ok. Try step 2 set permision 777 project/storage and project/bootstrap/cache

Comment: Appreciated Tai Ho, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tutorial will help you [Deploy Laravel To Shared Hosting The Easy Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4&t=2s)

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow this Steps:

1.public folder(index.php) is the start point of your application set

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

according to your configuration or use symlink

2.Migrate Database (if you don't have ssh access create a route and use Artisan facade `Artisan::call("migrate");` and don't forget to remove it )

3.Link storage if you need (if you don't have ssh access create a route and use Artisan facade `Artisan::call("storage:link");` and don't forget to remove it )

4.Check server logs maybe folder premissions is wrong.